# How can i change the action of the Save Button in AdminHtml?

Tags: magento2, save

In the Save.php file in magento Catalog the Button is defined like this:

```
'label' => __('Save'),
        'class' => 'save primary',
        'data_attribute' => [
            'mage-init' => [
                'buttonAdapter' => [
                    'actions' => [
                        [
                            'targetName' => 'product_form.product_form',
                            'actionName' => 'save',
                            'params' => [
                                false
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ],
```

At first i thought that action Name was the name of the action of the controller but if i change it with my 'mymodule/mycontroller/save' it doesn't do anything.
Searching in the Magento2 official documentation i found that there is a ButtonActionInterface defined somewhere.
My question is:

> What actually is the action used in the button and where is the file
>   where it is defined.

Thanks in advance for the help.